# How to multiply Lab elements in Numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to multiply Lab(color) element in Numply arrays but I obtained different result from I expected.

```
img=cv2.imread('image.bmp', 1)
lab_img=cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
L, a,b=lab_img.T
L_value=L*2
```

With this code, I expected that each elements in L would be doubled as below.

---

```
L=array([[170, 168, 168, ...,   9,   9,   9],
         [171, 169, 169, ...,   9,   9,   9],
         [173, 172, 172, ...,  10,   9,  10],
         ...,
         [  9,   9,   9, ...,   9,   9,   9],
         [  9,   9,   9, ...,   9,   9,   9],
         [  9,   9,   9, ...,   9,   9,   1]], dtype=uint8)
```

---

```
L_value=array([[340, 336, 336,..., 18, 18, 18],
               [342, 338, 338,..., 18, 18, 18],
               [346, 344, 344,..., 20, 18, 20],
                ...,
               [18, 18, 18,..., 18, 18, 18],
               [18, 18, 18,..., 18, 18, 18],
               [18, 18, 18,..., 18, 18, 2]], dtype=unit8)
```

However I received

---

```
L_value=array([[84, 80, 80, ..., 18, 18, 18],
               [86, 82, 82, ..., 18, 18, 18],
               [90, 88, 88, ..., 20, 18, 20],
                ...,
               [18, 18, 18, ..., 18, 18, 18],
               [18, 18, 18, ..., 18, 18, 18],
               [18, 18, 18, ..., 18, 18,  2]], dtype=uint8)
```

What is happening and how I can get the result I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unsigned 8-bit datatype `dtype=uint8` restricts your numbers to the range `[0:255]`. When you multiply, say, 170 by 2, you get 340, but it is truncated to 84 (340=256+84).

Possible solution: change the datatype of your image to `uint16` with `L=L.astype(uint16)`.